# Java: Decrease value of primitive from getter or use setter?

Tags: java

Hello StackOverflow Community! I hope you're having a nice day.

I'm asking myself if I can just decrease an int obtained from a getXYZ() method of another class (the int should also be modified in the other class) or if I must use a setter?

for example:

Class: Monster

```
public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}
```

Class: Bullet

```
applyDamage(target);

private void applyDamage(Monster target) { 
    target.getHealth() - 1; // OR
    target.setHealth(4); 
}
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive around what the question is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean something like:

```
int value = object.getXYZ();
value--;
```

The code is valid but will not set the `int` in the other class. It will only decrease the value of the local variable you use to store the value.

```
 object.setXYZ(object.getXYZ() - 1);
```

Is what you're looking for.

This answer assumes that the `int` you want to set in the other class has the `private` modifier. If it is declared `public` you can just use `object.XYZ--;` for example.

Answer (score 1):

you can't change the original int value that you get from the getter because you get his value, not his place in the memory.
to change the original value, you have to use setter(if the int is not static).
in addition, it make the code more readable and organized

Answer (score 0):

If you call a `getXYZ()` which return an `int` and then edit the `int`, the `int` in the class containing the int will not be changed.
Because you will have  the value of  that  int not that `int` it self. You can say you will have your personal copy. Now whatever you do with you copy it will affect the main `int`.

**You have to call the setter in that case.**

```
private void applyDamage(Monster target) { 
    target.setHealth(target.getHealth() - 1); 
}
```